# xamarin forms xlabs checkbox

Tags: checkbox, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I am new to Xamarin forms. I was trying to implement Checkboxes in my project.

I referred this link : 
https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-create-checkboxes-in-xamarin-forms/

So, I added the mentioned nuget package and added this line in my xaml page :
`xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"`

These errors came up

> Framework resource extraction failed. Item named
>   'controls/sensorbar/sensorbarcontrol.xaml' of type
>   'System.IO.PinnedBufferMemoryStream' cannot be added to the resource
>   file because it is not serializable.  App.UWP
>
> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot
>   resolve assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8, Version=1.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.'    App.UWP

And i am not able to get rid of them. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This great library is outdated and unfortunately should not be used anymore.
 There are few options:

1. Check how did `Checkbox` control was implemented in `XLabs.Forms.Controls` since it is open source project and build your own using.
2. Check other existing libraries like [Forms.Controls](https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Controls)
3. There are also blogposts on this topic like [Xamarin.Tip – Build Your Own CheckBox in Xamarin.Forms](https://alexdunn.org/2018/04/10/xamarin-tip-build-your-own-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms/)

Good luck.

Comment: I explored different packages and found this one, seems to be working fine https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit